# Not able to connect to SQL Server 2005 through pyodbc using windows authentication

Tags: python, sql-server-2005, windows-authentication, pyodbc

I am not able to connect to SQL Server 2005 using pyodbc through windows authentication.

I'm getting `error 4060 Login failed`

Comment: Can you provide code or some more information?

Comment: issue resolved, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved. I was trying to put double quotes around my password while trying to login no "" required